# PHP pagination not changing when next button is pressed

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am trying to do a simple pagination where it'll retrieve data from MySQL and show a previous and next button, no numbers for counting pages, although once the next button is pressed no information are updated, I am not sure if I should use a while or foreach loop.

### query

`pageClass.php`

```
public function classname 
{
    $start_page = 0;
    $per_page = 8;

    if(!isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $page = 1;
    } else {   
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }

    if($page<=1)
        $start_page = 0;
    else
    $start_page = $page * $per_page - $per_page;

    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_uid DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
    $sth->execute(array($start_page, $per_page));

    $row = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $row;
}
```

then in a .php file I am displaying it this way, I get the titles but once the buttons are pressed, no other page is opened.

`index.php`

```
foreach($latestArticles as $article)
{  
    $title = $latest['title'];

    echo '<div>'.$title.'</div>';

}

$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;

echo "
    <a href='?page=$prev'>prev</a>
    <a href='?page=$next'>next</a>
";
```

I don't want to put div's in the php classes as it would be a pain to find each class in folders to edit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `echo`, `var_dump` or `print_r` each step - that way you'll be able to find where things go wrong.

Comment: $_GET['page'], but how you send this data to _GET? where is form?

Comment: @sergio for GET a form is not needed. The page is passed in the URL in the links on the very bottom of the second code block

Comment: is `$page` **EVER** defined in your index.php? If it's not, yhour next/prev links are ALWAYS going to be `page=-1` and `page=1`.

Answer (score 0):

First i would recommend you to change your `pageClass.php` to something more abstract

```
<?PHP
  class pageClass
  {
    private $db;
    private $articlesPerPage = 8;
    private $startPage = 0;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
      #TODO check if $db is valid PDO
      $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function setArticlesPerPage($articlesPerPage)
    {
      $this->articlesPerPage = $articlesPerPage;
    }

    public function setStartPage($startPage)
    {
      $this->startPage = $startPage;
    }

    public function getArticles()
    {
      $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
      $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY article_uid DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
      $queryResult = $query->execute(array($this->startPage, $this->articlesPerPage));
      return $queryResult;
    }
  }
```

Try to change your `index.php` to the following

```
<?PHP

  $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
  $pageClass = new pageClass($pdo);

  if($page > 0)
  {
    $pageClass->setStartPage($page);
  }

  $lastestArticles = $pageClass->getArticles();
  foreach($lastestArticles as $article)
  {
    echo '<div>'.$article['title'].'</div>';
  }

  echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$page-1.'">prev</a>';
  echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$page+1.'">next</a>';
?>
```

**NOTE: THIS IS EXAMPLE CODE. YOU SHOULD EDIT IT BEFORE COMMITING TO PRODUCTION**